# Why do hash tables store key values in addition to data values?

Tags: python, data-structures

Is it because comparison of `_key\_a_ == _key\_b_` is faster than `_datum\_a_ == _datum\_b_` for non-trivial data objects?

For context, see [this codeblock](https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/pythonds3/SortSearch/Hashing.html#lst-hashtablecodestore).

Comment: I see what you're saying, but you don't need to store a key->value pair's key in order to get the value out. You just input it into the hash function and get the slot-index of the data.

I need to read the implementation for a Python set. Maybe a set is implemented in the way I'm describing, a Hash Table that doesn't store the Keys

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for responses. No particular case– I'm currently learning DS&As and didn't see a purpose for two lists in the naive use-case and figured I was wrong so I asked.

Comment: "you don't need to store a key->value pair's key in order to get the value out" you do. Consider two keys `a` and `b` that both map to index `5`. You pass in key `b`, is the value at index `5` `a` or `b`? You need to have stored the key to deal with collisions.

Comment: Ah perfect, that makes sense. Thank you @Welbog.

Comment: "You just input it into the hash function and get the slot-index of the data" no you can't, that assumes you have a perfect hash function, which in the general case you don't.

Comment: My apologies. I appear to have grossly misunderstood what was being asked. Please disregard my comments.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, I'm sure my question was phrased poorly. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it because comparison of key_a == key_b is faster than datum_a == datum_b for non-trivial data objects?

No, since keys are arbitrary and can be nontrivial themselves.

The reason is to handle collisions correctly.

Imagine if we *didn't* store the key. `put('a', 50)`, let's say the key `a` hashes to index 5. Now `get('a')`, you get `50`, so far so good.

Now `put('b', 40)`, and `b` also hashes to index 5. So we rehash `b`, say we get 7. If you `get('b')`, you will get `50`, not `40`, because `b` hashes to index 5. Since `a` isn't stored at index 5, `get('b')` has no way to know it should rehash because the key at index 5 doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

The general contract of an arbitrary object k, used as a key in a hash table in any language, is roughly the following:

1. a function equals(k1, k2) must be defined
2. a function hash(k) must be defined
3. if equals(k1, k2) then hash(k1) == hash(k2)

There are further rules for the proper behavior of a hash function but that it not really relevant to this question.

Note that rule (3) does not imply the reverse. Unequal objects may have the same hash value, but if they are equal, their hashes MUST be equal.

Due to the possibly that two unequal keys collide (have the same hash), the implementation must store the key. Since the table can only store one key/value pair per slot, it must resolve collisions, typically using some linear structure (open addressing or chaining). Ultimately, the keys must be stored due to the collision problem, as they are needed to select the correct key/value pair among all of the keys that might exist in these linear structures.

It might be worthy to note that if you could prove that collisions were impossible, it would not be necessary to store the keys in the table.